# Django 1.11 enter_transaction_management alternative

Tags: python, django, django-1.11, django-nose

We are using django as our main backend, we use `django-nose` as our unit test framework. We have recently upgraded from django 1.3 to 1.11, a huge change, we are facing the following issue. When we are django 1.3, the unit tests ran fine, but with django 1.11, it's throwing the below error.

```
    transaction.enter_transaction_management(using=db)
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 
                      'enter_transaction_management'
```

We found that there is an opened issue going on in `django-nose` github.
I thought of two solutions for this problem.
1. As I can understand that `enter_transaction_management` and `managed` functions are deprecated/removed in django 1.11, were there any replacements or alternatives provided in 1.11???
2. What are the good alternatives to `django-nose`??

Please help

These are the github issues.

https://github.com/django-nose/django-nose/issues/226

https://github.com/django-nose/django-nose/issues/289

https://github.com/django-nose/django-nose/pull/258

Comment: Here's a note from the django docs about `TransactionTestCase` and what changed from Django 1.8 onwards: Changed in Django 1.8:
In older versions of Django, the effects of transaction commit and rollback could not be tested within a TestCase. With the completion of the deprecation cycle of the old-style transaction management in Django 1.8, transaction management commands (e.g. transaction.commit()) are no longer disabled within TestCase.

Comment: So you can just use Django's standard TransactionTestCase and use transactions as you would in your normal views inside your test cases. No need to use the extra function provided by django.nose for this.

Comment: @dirkgroten hi, thanks for reply... I have tried as you suggested, but the problem is it's not creating entries in database properly, the error I am getting is some field doesn't have a default value, but actually it does have a default value set. Don't know why??? do you have any idea on this...

Comment: sorry, would need to have more information: what error exactly? what's the test you're trying? which model?

Comment: hey @dirkgroten django-nose not re-using the database even with REUSE_DB=1 setting, do you have any idea on this???

Comment: sorry I can't help here. No idea.